# Trying to override CSS :hover

Tags: css, hover

I have an image that when rolled over transitions from grey to color. However, above that, I have an article that causes the hover to reset once I roll over the article. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see a simple example? Perhaps make one on http://jsfiddle.net? http://cssdesk.com?

Comment: Post your code or a jsFiddle example please.

Comment: a hover transition only applies when you're hovering over the item. once you move your mouse away from it, it no longer applies. You're going to most likely have to use JS.

Comment: Show us the money! Sorry, code :p

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery
include the latest Jquery js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
```

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myobject").hover(function(){
    $("myobject").css("background-color","yellow");
    },f#unction(){
    $("#myobject").css("background-color","#E9E9E4");
  });
});
</script>
```

This will work by id.

Replace # with . to reference by class

The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready.

I am making a few assumption provided that i haven't seen any code.